# Assert numeric predicates in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Is there a possibility in Prolog to assert facts that represent a number?
For example, I would like to use a predicate `distance/2` and assert facts like `distance(town1, city2) = 1200`.

Comment: no, use assert(distance(town1, city2, 1200)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `distance(town1, city2) = 1200` term is syntactic sugar for the term `'='(distance(town1, city2), 1200)` as `(=)/2` is a standard Prolog infix operator. `(=)/2` is also the standard unification built-in predicate. In most Prolog systems, built-in predicates cannot be redefined by the user. Thus, you cannot assert clauses for them as that would amount to redefine the predicate. Carlo's suggestion of using a `distance/3` predicate is likely the best solution.