# How to write numerical predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Similar to [a previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651442/assert-numeric-predicates-in-prolog), I'm trying to create a numerical function to calculate slope. As the answer for the aforementioned link indicates, and I'm discovering, I'm going to end up with an arity of 3 with a slope/3 that looks like this:

```
slope((Xa, Ya), (Xb, Yb), S) :-
    S is div((Yb - Ya), (Xb - Xa)).
```

My next question is: How do I use that? `S` will end up containing either `1` or `-1` but, as a prolog newbie, I can't see how I would use that in a rule. Is it

```
 answer((Xa, Ya), (Xb, Yb)) :- slope((Xa, Ya), (Xb, Yb), 1), slope((Xa, Ya), (Xb, Yb), -1).
```

or something else?

Comment: Side note: http://hopl.info/ fails.

Comment: I saw your user number: `user:426`, nice!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your predicate:

```
answer((Xa, Ya), (Xb, Yb)) :-
    slope((Xa, Ya), (Xb, Yb), 1),
    slope((Xa, Ya), (Xb, Yb), -1).
```

says that the slope between `(Xa, Ya)` and `(Yb, Yb)` should be `1`; *and* the slope between `(Xa, Ya)` and `(Yb, Yb)` should be `-1`. Unless the slope can have two values, that will not happen.

Furthermore, I am not convinced that using the slope here is a good idea anyway. If `Xb-Xa` is zero, then this will result in an evaluation error, since you divide by zero.

You could say the slope of two values is `1` or `-1` given that the absolute value of the difference between `Yb` and `Ya` is the same as the absolute value of the difference between `Xb` and `Ya`.

We can express that with:

```
answer((Xa, Ya), (Xb, Yb)) :-
    abs(Xa - Xb) =:= abs(Ya - Yb).
```

Comment: I like that you used a declarative reading for your solution.